# Is there a Ruby equivalent to the C++ std::setw(int) function?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, ruby-std

I am outputting some text tables to a terminal and would like to be able to use something like the C++ std::setw() function to provide padding for my output rather than guessing at the number of spaces or tabs required.  Before I go knock together something to do this, is there already a function or Ruby Gem which does this?

Std::setw() for those who need a few cobwebs flow out (like me) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/

I am using Ruby 1.8 at present so a solution compatible with that would be preferable.

Comment: Are you searching for something similar to String#ljust and String#rjust?

Comment: Yes christianblais, I could use that to pre-format my strings or call it in line.  I totally overlooked that function when I was skimming through the Ruby docs. I don't know if you solution is better than d11wtq's but it should do the job in most cases.  Thanks for your comment/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same interface (so slightly different thinking), but if I understand the purpose correctly, I usually just use `sprintf` for this.

```
puts "%10s" % ["foo"]  # => "       foo"
puts "%-10s" % ["bar"] # => "foo       "
```

Comment: Perfect, `puts "%-10s" % ["bar"] # => "foo       "` is what I was hoping for but thanks for giving me both ways as I am sure it will come in useful.  I am still far to use to thinking in C++ streams for output & totally forgot about sprintf for C which is a much more Ruby like output system.  Thanks for your answer :-)