# How to format string in Ruby using printf/sprintf

Tags: ruby, spacing

I want to create a table:

```
Iterations                      Value
         1                      123  
         2                      124
        ..                      
       100                      124212
       101                      1242142
```

If I'm able to do so, do you know which website for reference is good for Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Already asked here:
[Is there a Ruby equivalent to the C++ std::setw(int) function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309931/is-there-a-ruby-equivalent-to-the-c-stdsetwint-function)

```
puts "%10s" % ["foo"]  # => "       foo"
puts "%-10s" % ["bar"] # => "foo       "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rjust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rjust) or [`ljust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-ljust).

```
"123".rjust(10, '0')
#=> "0000000123"
"123".ljust(10, '0')
#=> "1230000000"
```